# Python and Wordpress, slow XMLRPC calls

Tags: python, wordpress

Well lately I’m trying to work with remote posts upload. But i see that – because i am doing a lot of calls – each call after another is slower and slower. I am using python's python-wordpress-xmlrpc library.

It is like WordPress has some kind of mechanism to slow down the calls if they are many. I contacted my host provider but he said that they didnt lock anything and it has something to do with WordPress security maybe. Anyone has come across this situation?

- I am not using any kind of plugins or security, I tested it in a clean Wordpress environment.
- I tried to call the function with and without "safe transport" option (User-agent etc).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How many filters does your provider apply? You can only make RPC calls at high speed and intensity on a server. Redirects are always slow, filtering your packages takes too long (4 + steps). If you only process the first 34-40 bytes of a packet, it can be a real time application. It is absolutely incorrect for RPC applications to be made with the Web page. Setting the access permissions is very annoying.

Comment: It's impossible to diagnose the problem without more informations. You should build a MCVE for the python part (minimal code required to reproduce the problem), and make sure you can indeed reproduce the problem on a _local_ vanilla WP install.